# Alter field instance settings form on admin/structure/types/manage/<content type>/fields/node.<content type>.<fieldname>/storage

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to figure out how to add an extra field to content type field settings page.

Basically I want to alter field instance settings form on **admin/structure/types/manage//fields/node../storage** .

I'm going with **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter for FORM_ID field_config_edit_form**.
The new form element appears on the form but after submit I'm not able to see the value.

Am I missing something? Is an extra form submit function required other than the default one to submit my new value?

Here is my snippet -

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymod_form_field_storage_config_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['enabled'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Enable'),
      '#description' => t('If enabled then this module will alter the field settings.'),
      '#default_value' => $form['enabled'],
  );
}
```

Comment: Extra fields in config entities are stored in the ThirdPartySettings, see https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-8-custom-data-configuration-entities-using-thirdpartysettingsinterface

Comment: Ok, I can see the use of `$form['#entity_builders'][]` and `ThirdPartySettingsInterface` . Will try it out and update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example -

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymod_form_field_storage_config_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['enabled'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Enable'),
      '#description' => t('If enabled then this module will alter the field settings.'),
      '#default_value' => $form['enabled'],
  );

  $form['#entity_builders'][] = '_my_additional_form_field_storage_submit';
}

/**
 * Entity builder.
 */
function _my_additional_form_field_storage_submit($entity_type, Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig $fieldStorageConfig, &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  if ($form_state->getValue('enabled')) {
    $fieldStorageConfig->setThirdPartySetting('my_additional_settings', 'enabled', $form_state->getValue('enabled'));
  }
  return true;
}
```